# Is the intersection connected if union is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It is well-known that intersection of connected sets is not necessarily connected. A standard example is two half-circles, which intersect in a discrete set $\{a,b\}$.

However, Mayer-Vietoris says that if we replace things by path-connectedness and suppose that $X=\mathrm{int}(A)\cup \mathrm{int}(B)$ is simply connected, then the result holds.

More precisely, given sets $A, B \subset X$ such that $A,B$ are path-connected and $X=\mathrm{int}(A) \cup \mathrm{int}(B)$ is simply connected, then $A \cap B$ is also path-connected (note the problem with the standard example: the circle is not simply connected).

My question therefore is: does the above hold for connectedness? Explicitly,

**Given sets $A, B \subset X$ such that $A,B$ are connected and $X=\mathrm{int}(A) \cup \mathrm{int}(B)$ is simply connected, is $A \cap B$ connected?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No this is not true. You can modify the standard example of two half circles with "half circles" of the topologist's circle. This ensures that the union is simply connected but you get the same result as with the usual half circles.

Answer (score 13):

No, this is not true in general (at least not without further assumptions on the two sets $A$ and $B$, such as both being open or both closed).

Imagine a solid rectangle. You can draw two L-shaped sets $A$ and $B$ in your rectangle, one of which is open, and the other closed, such that their union is the entire space, but their intersection consists of 2 disjoint rectangles.

**Edit**: Here is a picture of the counterexample:
[image]

**Edit 2:** The question has been edited so that $\mathrm{int}(A) \cup \mathrm{int}(B)$ is simply connected. In this case this example no longer works for obvious reasons, but I will leave the answer here as a counterexample to the more general situation where $A$ and $B$ can be any subsets of the space.

Comment: Sorry to come back now. I've forgotten the important fact that we must have $X=\mathrm{int}(A) \cup \mathrm{int}(B)$ for Mayer-Vietoris to hold. Thus, the answer does not hold (as I have effectively changed the question). Of course, the blame is on me for forgetting. I'll leave the answer upvoted, and sorry for the nuisance.